# Creating dashboards that pull data from a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages

I've been tasked with creating a budget control dashboard. I have a SharePoint list generated from a custom content type. This list contains information such as name, cost center, and fields that represent the employees position scheduling information. I would like to create a table to display the information, including calculating averages of columns an so on, with the list displayed underneath. I've created similar applications before using xslt and SharePoint Designer, but I'd like to venture into Visual Studio to create this one. Thing is, I'm not sure as how to proceed in terms of layout. I'm seeking advice or resources on how to create SharePoint 2010 apps that combine dashboards and lists. I know this is a fairly nebulous question, I apologize for that. I'm looking for an overview - maybe how you would layout, in general, something like this. Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way, I'm not sure. Any information is appreciated and I can provide more information if needed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Reporting Services if available in your SharePoint Farm is capable of creating some really sophisticated Dashboards.  Check with your Server Admin to see if it is deployed.  It may not satisfy your craving for .NET development, but the capabilities that that SSRS and the SSRS webpart provide are very cool and will definitely impress your executives and managers!

[MSDN Blog: Report Builder 3.0 and SharePoint Lists](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msfedtech/archive/2010/06/29/report-builder-3-0-and-sharepoint-lists.aspx)
[MSDN sharePoint Server 2010 business intelligence insights training](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hh126809.aspx)
[MSDN: Getting Started with Report Builder 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey thats great! We will be implementing SSRS / SharePoint in the near future. I wasnt aware that we could query lists that way. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, you most certainly can.  There are a lot of tutorials for SSRS that start off by building your dataset against a SQL Server.  Just replace it with a dataset against a SharePoint list and you should be able to follow along with the rest of the tutorial.  However, keep in mind that it does get trickier when dealing with multiple lists--TSQL has the advantage of easily building joined queries, something that is much tougher and error prone in CAML.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend sticking with XSLT and maybe jQuery if needed.  This client-side code is more aligned with 2013 and O365 and is more than capable of achieving a dashboard.  If you develop a custom feature then you are into the realms of deploying to your SharePoint environment, IISRESET every time you need to tweak etc.

I appreciate there are times when server-side development is needed but I would avoid it if it is at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So something like an asp/html dashboard that uses event handlers, ajax to update from the list ? Again, I appreciate your comment.

Comment: You can either use a web part or REST to grab the data from the list.  If you use a web part - data view, list view or CQWP - then XSLT can be used to present the data - including averages etc - in a dashboard.  If you use REST then use jQuery to process the data and output into your dashboard.  There are a couple of examples (dashboard and risk matrix) on my blog - http://paylord.wordpress.com